# DB2 - table contains data but a select statement on specific columns returns empty

Tags: sql, select, db2

The database is DB2.

A table contains data, and "*SELECT * FROM TABLE1*" statement returns the data correctly.

However the statements like the following return empty:

*SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1*

Also *SELECT COUNT(COL1) FROM TABLE1* returns ZERO but SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 returns the correct result.

The table contains 7 columns, and only 3 columns of them have such a problems, all the other columns are fine.

This is the first time I met such a situation in recent 10 years.

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT NVL2 (COL1, 'NOT NULL', 'NULL') AS GRP, COUNT (1) AS CNT FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY NVL2 (COL1, 'NOT NULL', 'NULL')`?

Comment: platform and version of Db2?

Comment: I have seen comparable behavior when MQTs are defined on that table - che ck it out.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, the result is empty.

Comment: The query I provided counts NULL and NOT NULL values in this column. The empty result set means, that the table contains no rows unless the query is really routed to some MQT. If it's db2 for LUW, then attach here an access plan of the query returning incorrect result from the `db2exfmt` utility.

Comment: Can you reproduce the case in a fiddle so we can all look at it in detail? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1

Comment: have you any Column Access Contro ? https://www.choudharysumit.com/2021/05/data-masking-in-db2.html